# MySQL query getting wrong result in API

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting result from database from all shops from a particular services.

I need result from particular shop So I pass `shop_id` in API, it should show me all services under that a shop. But instead it shows all services from all shops.

[image: Database]

la_service - Services Table
la_price_list - Items (products)

Here is my function and query

```php
     public function getItembyShopId($shop_id)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('shop_id', 'shop_id', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) 
        {
            $this->Api_Auth_model->responseFailed(0,ALL_FIELD_MANDATORY);
            exit();
        }
        $query = $this->db->where('shop_id',$shop_id)->where('status','1')->get('la_price_list')->num_rows();
        if($query > 0)
        {
            $price_list = $this->Api_Price_list_model->getPriceforService($shop_id);
            $price_lists = array();
            foreach($price_list as $price_list)
            {
            // $service = $this->Api_Price_list_model->getAllDataWhere(array(
            //     'service_id' => $price_list->service_id
            // ), 'la_price_list');
                $service = $this->Api_Price_list_model->getAllDataWhere1($price_list->service_id);
            
                $cur = $this->db->where('status','1')->get('la_currency')->row_array();
                $data['currency_code'] = $cur['currency_symbol'];
                
                $price_list->services = $service;
                array_push($price_lists, $price_list);
                $data['item_list'] = $price_lists;
            }
            return $data;

        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public function getAllDataWhere1($service_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('pl.*,s.service_name');
       // $this->db->select('CONCAT("'.base_url().'assets/images/Product/",pl.image) as image');
        $this->db->from('la_price_list pl');
        $this->db->join('la_service s', 's.service_id = pl.service_id');

        $this->db->where('pl.service_id',$service_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function getPriceforService($shop_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('pl.service_id,s.service_name');

        $this->db->from('la_price_list pl');
        $this->db->join('la_service s', 's.service_id = pl.service_id');

        $this->db->where('pl.shop_id',$shop_id);
        $this->db->group_by('pl.service_id'); 
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

API Post request for particular shop
[image: API Post Request]

Here is API Response - Here you can see, There are other shop_id's are present as well.

[image: APi Response Pic]

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Have you checked whether the query that is generated works properly?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried to put shop_id in query but seems like I'm making some mistakes, Added API response screenshot as well.

Comment: Please do not share pure text content hidden in images. Also, share your attempts to resolve the problem